# View Frame differs IOS 4.3 vs IOS 5.1 -- Why?

Tags: ios

In laying out CALayer objects in the main view of a viewController I am seeing a discrepancy between IOS 43. and 5.1

I am running in landscape mode.  I want a CALayer object 40 pts wide, showing at the top left -- butted up against the nav bar and the full height of the screen (less the nav bar).  Status bar is disabled. I calculate the height of the layer as the height of the view less the height of the nav bar.

In viewDidLoad of my viewController I have the following code....

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
float navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

CGRect f = CGRectMake( 0, navBarHeight, 40, viewFrame.size.height - navBarHeight);
leftLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
leftLayer.frame = f;
leftLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;  // for debug
[self.view.layer addSublayer:leftLayer];
```

When I run this on 5.1 viewFrame = (0, 0, 480, 288) and navBarHeight = 32.  When I run this on 4.3 viewFrame = (0, 0, 480, 320) and navBarHeight = 32.  I've tried the same comparison in portrait mode and there is no discrepancy between OS versions.

navBarHeight also seems wrong -- because my green CALayer object has about 12 pts of white space between it and the nav bar.   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have better luck with using the viewWillAppear method to adjust frames because the view has been sized for the orientation by then. Do you have the same issue in that method?

Comment: The inconsistency between the two OS versions disappears when I move the layout activity to viewWillAppear.  However, the numbers are off -- viewFrame shows as (0,0,480,268).  Adding a navBarHeight of 32 this adds to 300.  Where are the other 20 pts on the screen?  So the test CALayer shows on the screen with about 10 pts between it and the nav bar more at the bottom.